# sticky header smoothing scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I am creating a sticky header and it works fine but my problem is on "jump" when someone scroll down the page jumping some pixels and has no smoothness. I find some similar topics but I can not make it work for my website,

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById("my_header");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}

window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
```

```css
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:999;
  padding:18px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 1.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 1.3s;
  -o-transition: all 1.3s;
  transition: all 1.3s; 
    opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.75s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="topnavbar"></div>
<div id="my_header" style="width:1150px; background: #181818;">   
  <div style="width: 100%;margin: -18px auto 0; padding: 0;"> 
    <div id="header"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content"> ... </div>
```

you can find the demo at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oipeirates/y41f98dg/39/) too.

my website is [oipeirates.tv](https://oipeirates.tv)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) This is a ready solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's get rid of this unnecessary transitions. Do you want to achieve this effect?

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:999;
  padding:18px 0 0 0;
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 0.75s; 
}
 @keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oipeirates/y41f98dg/39/

Comment: i dont have problem to remove the transition or animation i just want to make it smooth with no jumping. but im totally tilted im trying so much days and i cant do this :/

Answer (score 0):

Specify what you want to animate, change `transition: all 1.3s;` to `transition: opacity 1.3s;`. Now the `padding:18px 0 0 0;` will not be animated, and the jumping behavior of the sticky header will be prevented.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/y41f98dg/54/

Answer (score 0):

i dont have problem to remove the transition or animation i just want to make it smooth with no jumping. but im totally tilted im trying so much days and i cant do this :/